# How to access a variable or a value of a function inside another function

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs

I have function it has a promise whose value i want  to use in another function

```
Submit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var email = this.refs.email.value;
        var pass = this.refs.pass.value;

        if (email && pass !== '' ) {
            const auth = firebase.auth();
            const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
            promise.catch(e => { console.log(e.message) });
            promise.then(() => {
                console.log('Logged in');
            })

        } 
    }
```

Now i want to use this e.message object inside my another function down below:

```
  renderError: function() {
                   if (error) {
                       <Error custom{//here i want to use that e.message}/>
    }
 }
```

Comment: is `renderError` a method of the same class that has `Submit` method?

Comment: yes they are in a same class

Answer (score 0):

As you said, because that method belongs to the same class of the `Submit` you can refer it via `this`...

```js
class LoginForm {
  submit() {
    let 
      email = 'test@test.com',
      pass = '1235'
    ;


    return firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
      .then(
        this.renderSuccess.bind(this),
        this.renderError.bind(this)
    );
  }

  renderError(error) { console.log('error', error); }
  renderError(response) { console.log('success', response); }
}
```

Comment: No need to bind in this case.

Comment: if you don't bind you loose the ability to refer to the component... you always need to bind.

Comment: No, in this case error message is passed directly, and then can be used by `Error` component, so yes - looks like there is no need to bind.

Comment: how can you render `the email {{this.refs.email.value}} provided is not valid`?

Comment: You are right that if you need `this` then one would need to bind or use arrow function, but I would probably make sure error message passed into `renderError` already formatted.

Comment: there are no `arrow function`s, and, just as an architecture concern, a method of an object must always have the ability to refer on its context, even when not needed.

Comment: No arrow functions? Well if you care about architecture then you should also not use error callback like you are using, and go with `catch` (e.g. `.catch(e => this.renderError(e.message))`).

Comment: Ok, there is confusion... `catch(callback)` is just an alias of `then(null, callback)` and `method(() => method())` is just a way to wrap a function in a further function... absolutely not needed.

Comment: There is a very significant difference why `catch` is always preferred over your version with `then`. And arrow function version would allow to preserve  context without binding.

Comment: it seems an endless discussion, I prefer `catch` because is more readable than passing the second parameter to a `then`, but, `then` doesn't mean success... and `catch` is an alias. I also agree that using a (fat) function allow to preserve the context without binding, but, in this case... how these two things make my answer wrong?